# Multiple Results of Scalar to select

Tags: sql, loops, scalar

I have a table of dates that is passed into a scalar function:

select getVal('1/1/1') returns a float.

I'm looping through my table of dates and setting @date,
then saving the result to @result and then performing a log on that value.

How can I get multiple results (with multiple scalar calls) without doing a loop? I've been told to try to stay away from doing loops inside of sql, and that there's a better way to perform this operation.

Example:

```
@DateTable
ID  Dates
1   1/1/1
2   1/3/1
3   1/4/1
4   1/2/2
5   1/3/2
6   4/15/12

set @k = 1
while @k <= (select count(ID) from @DateTable)
begin
  set @date = select Dates from @DateTable where ID = @k
  set @result = (select mySchema.getVal(@date))
  insert into @ResTable(result,logged) values (@result, LOG(@result))
  set @k = @k + 1
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a schema, sample data, expected data, and whatever code you have that works today?

Comment: What does "performing a log on that value" entail? What kind of sql database are you using? Is getVal() a scalar function you defined? What does it do?

Comment: Went ahead and added an example on how my data looks. Scalar function only returns a float value, and only one value, but I'm not allowed to modify the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this to:

```
INSERT @ResTable (Result, Logged)
SELECT  d.Result, LOG(Result)
FROM    (   SELECT  Result = mySchema.getVal(Dates)
            FROM    @DateTable
        ) AS d;
```

I suspect if you show what `mySchema.getVal()` does, it can probably be made more efficient still.

---

To answer the comment - If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer you can use the `LEAD/LAG` functions, something like:

```
SELECT  Dates,
        PreviousDate = LAG(Dates) OVER (ORDER BY Dates),
        NextDate = LEAD(Dates) OVER (ORDER BY Dates)
FROM    @DateTable;
```

If you are using earlier versions you will need to use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT  Dates,
        PreviousDate = prev.Dates
FROM    @DateTable AS dt
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Dates
            FROM    @DateTable AS Prev
            WHERE   Prev.Dates < dt.Dates
            ORDER BY Dates DESC
        ) AS prev;
```

Comment: I'd say you're right, but I can't modify getVal(). Bonus points if you know how to do getVal(Dates,Dates-1) as in the date and then the previous date inside of that table. But this clarifies how I can get around loops, which was my main problem. Accepted.